# How can I embed a Manipulate (or other interactive graphics) in my website using CDF?

Tags: cdf-format

The new [CDF (computable document format)](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) lets you embed a `Manipulate` or other interactive graphics on your website, and users can play around with your little script using the free player.

What steps do I need to follow to

1. Create the CDF file correctly so that it displays a static picture (that I choose) if the user doesn't have the player and fires up the player if they do?
2. Make the necessary changes to my website/server to enable this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### UPDATE

See: [Why does Wolfram Research no longer support the CDF plugin?](https://support.wolfram.com/20057?src=wolfram-player)

Then: [Web Delivery: Cloud](https://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery-cloud.html)

Also: [Wolfram Notebook Embedder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/)

### LEGACY

This is just to update everyone on this topic. Wolfram Research released detailed blog and video tutorial **["CDF Embedding in a Nutshell"](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/02/22/mathematica-qa-series-cdf-embedding-in-a-nutshell/)**. It shows how to use built-in Mathematica wizard to deploy CDF online into HTML pages and Word Press blogs. URL:

http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/02/22/mathematica-qa-series-cdf-embedding-in-a-nutshell/

Comment: I followed your CDF Embedding video and tried to do the same thing but I faced a problem. After copying the Interactive Cell, I went to `FIle` then tried to find `Deploy` but I cannot find the `Deploy` option. I am using MMA 11.03 version. What should I do now? Thanks.

Comment: @TugrulTemel I updated my post, see above.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: I deployed my `Manipulate` code to `WolframCloud`. No problem. But how can I: (1) allow non-Mathematica users to use it and (2) embed it into my own Webpage? Really, I tried many things but no success.

Comment: I think `EmbedCode[]` does the job. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13):

For part 2, you must add the following to your `<head>` section

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/plugin/v2.1/cdfplugin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cdf = new cdfplugin();
    cdf.embed('/path/to/filename.cdf', width, height);
</script>
```

For part 1, you can embed a static picture for people with no CDF plugin by using the `cdf.setDefaultContent` function:

```
cdf.setDefaultContent('<p>Your replacement content</p>');
cdf.embed('/path/to/additional.cdf', width, height);
```

For more details, see the [Web Delivery](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html) page.

Answer (score 7):

You could look at the following:

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html

That also explains, the wizard to create the html code for your web page.

**Edit:** OP wanted a precis:

Select you manipulate cell and choose (v.8.0.4): File -> Deploy.
That will generate the HTML automaticaly.

Comment: I do not see it in 8.0.1 on OS X. is this Deploy menu item only in 8.0.4, only in windows, or am I missing something else?

Comment: @acl, yes, this is one of the few new features in V8.0.4