# How can I share objects with dynamic content with non-Mathematica users?

Tags: graphics, export, dynamic, cdf-format

Often when I construct some cool `Manipulate[]` function, I would like to share it with others—non-Mathematica users.  Some software, notably [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/tiki-index.php), supports exporting some dynamic calculations to a Java applet.  I can see why this would be very difficult to achieve with Mathematica, for it would require exporting all the under-the-hood calculations to Java.

Nevertheless, how do you all share dynamic results from Mathematica to others on the web?
Often I resort to `Export["filename.gif", {img1, img2, ...}, "GIF"]` to share animations.  What better alternatives are available?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3/5) if you'd like to embed them in your website.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not need to export an applet to be able to share things with non-Mathematica users. If you save your stuff as a [CDF](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) then other non-Mathematica people will be able to use it both on their desktops or view it in webpages (if you choose to embed your CDFs in a webpage). You can do this via File > Deploy

[image: screenshot of appropriate menu]

See also ref/format/CDF in the documentation center and the *How To* that is linked at the bottom.

Also some additional things that may help you:

[#1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-embed-a-manipulate-or-other-interactive-graphics-in-my-website-using)
[#2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75/what-are-the-exact-guidelines-for-what-is-allowed-in-a-cdf)
[#3](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3323)

Comment: Wonderful!  I didn't know about CDF.  Thanks so much! :-)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Please note that there are certain restrictions to CDF documents. Import/Export are highly restricted (if possible at all). Additionally, the CDf should be centered around a single Manipulate.

Comment: So, is it the case that anyone who wants to see a CDF must download something, as per Nasser's comment?  For the casual passerby, this is an impediment...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke Well, you could always use http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/ which only requires Java if you're satisfied with an animation that people can rotate...