# Start Mathematica without the menu bar?

Tags: front-end

Is there any way to start Mathematica without the main menu bar? To be precise:

[image: what is the menu bar]

Sometimes I make standalone mini-applications that I would like to just have in their own little windows without the cognitive weight of the entire Mathematica system bearing down upon my little one-off uses.

Comment: I almost ask this question two days ago. Finally, I forgot, hehe.

Comment: To me the top bar feels like the developers are trying to make Windows into a Mac.  In case anyone is wondering Linux doesn't have the bar at the top but in each individual window.

Comment: Reverse question: [(57593)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57593/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be what you want, but when you mentioned "mini-application" I immediately thought of the `CDF` notebook format which you can embed in HTML pages. In effect, everything at http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ is a mini-application of sorts. And there are no *Mathematica* menu bars... just those of the browser. I know, it's cheating.

However, if you're serious about standalone applications, you may want to look into `CDF` anyway. The rationale is outlined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5249/245).

Comment: To push it further, it is even possible to embed the CDF and the JS (and eventually a "no plug-in installed" message image) inside an unique MHT file, which means you end up with a single file that opens in a web browser. And most likely, the HTML code can make the browser menu bar disappear.

Comment: Unfortunately CDF doesn't allow text fields. (Or the free version doesn't anyway). Either way it's only the bar that bothers me. I quickly made up a program that follows your WebView suggestion and that would work well for setups that don't have text fields, and I could automate the construction if need be. But it's quite disappointing that I have to resort to haxing. And on the topic of CDF, the bar is even more awkward with it as a "document" format (PDFs for example don't plaster a non-sequitur masterbar over your screen).

Comment: That's true - it has a clunky feel to it...

Answer (score 8):

In version 10.0 of Mathematica the main menu bar is gone, just as you want it. And each window has its own menu bar.

[image]

Comment: ¡¡ WE DID IT REDDIT !!