# Can the toolbar be moved to the code window?

Tags: interface

Is there any way to move Mathematica's toolbar window so it is just part of the current notebook's window?  I usually just work with one notebook at a time and it is pretty annoying to have to have two windows.

Comment: [Here is](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5603/187), unfortunately with no clear answer, almost the same question. I never saw this on someones machine (I don't use Widnwos) and I don't think it is possible.

Comment: Protip: Windows machines are equipped with a special feature for most applications.  Not many people know about this, but in the top right corner of the MMA window is a button that sort of looks like an underscore or hyphen.  Clicking it makes the window, like, disappear!!

Comment: @VF1 Just because you don't know the answer doesn't mean you need to post a smart-ass comment.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't resist.  My aim was to make people laugh - I don't see what's wrong with that.

Comment: @VF1 Ok, ok, ok.  That makes sense.  I'm guess I'm just used to the SuperUser community - where every other comment is someone being an ass.