# Is it possible to embed a notebook as a panel in a java GUI?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction

I'd like to create a GUI that displays a tree, some text boxes, buttons, and then as a panel, a fully-functional notebook.  Is that possible?

Comment: Try putting a [`PaletteNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PaletteNotebook.html) where you want it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use GUI-kit? Since the arrival of version 6, more than 5 years ago, this has been been pretty much been obsolete.

Comment: Well, no, actually.  I want to embed it in a GUI constructed in java.  I thought I came across a way to do this in the documentation, but I can't find it now.  @ssch, thanks I will check that out.

Comment: Maybe with "native Swing": http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/index.html   But why do you really want to do that and not use CDF right away?

Comment: related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5603/start-mathematica-without-the-menu-bar . the "solution" there is to host an HTML page that contains the CDF object in an HTML View, which I'm sure the Java libraries have.

Comment: @Rolf, in this case I want to execute a complicated set of calculations and then give users an ability to explore the results in an ad hoc manner.  Hundreds of symbols are created during the calculation, so I won't be able to predict what they want to know.  A notebook would be the perfect object to embed, if it's possible.

Comment: I think I found it!  MathSessionPane

Answer (score 6):

I realized just now that I never came back and explained how I solved this problem.  I used the `MathSessionPane` class provided in `JLink`:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html#8928

It's not a fully fledged front end like you'd see in *Mathematica*, but it worked quite nicely.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: @Ruslan That's because they renamed everything to "Wolfram Language" .. fixed now.