# Showing Mathematica's dynamic UI in external Java programs

Tags: manipulate, mathlink-or-wstp, java

I want to run *Mathematica* from an external Java program and display an interactive app in my own Jpanel. Is it possible?

When I tried using MathGraphicsJpanel, I am getting only the snapshot of the app. I want to access the controls in my app.

For example, when I tried the following command `Manipulate[Plot[x^a, {x, 10, 100}], {a, 1, 3}]`, I am getting only this picture.

[image]

Is it even possible to get the Interactive ui of *Mathematica* in external java programs?

Comment: IIRC, the panel is not interactive, it's a display portal only.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are "running Mathematica" from an external java program or whether you have a "JLink connection to a Mathematica Kernel"?

Comment: I am new to Mathematica. I think I am running Mathematica from an external program via kernel link. I am using the following as reference.  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/WritingJavaProgramsThatUseTheWolframLanguage.html#24041

Comment: Duplicate question, but not a duplicate answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17526/12  I don't think it can be done in a reasonably robust way.  But who knows?

Comment: The link tells about embedding whole notebook. I need only the dynamic content. Embedding CDF matches with what I want but, I don't know if CDF can be embedded to Jpanel ?