# Is it possible to recover the style of the previous version(V8,V9) in Windows?

Tags: front-end

In Wolfram Mathematica 10 (Windows paltform),the menu bar and files are combined together.When I narrow the window，it will become ugly shown as below!

[image]

So my question is:

**Is it possible `recover the style of the previous version(V8,V9)`,**

or is it possible to construct a software interface like other software(**All files embedded below the menu bar and the main working windows has the normal size like `Microsoft Word`**).

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [(54599)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54599)

Answer (score 6):

Since in nearly a year nobody has offered a better answer I'll share all I can think to post.

You can remove the menu bar from a window by deleting the `"MenuBar"` item from the [`WindowElements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowElements.html) Option for the Notebook, which can be done by evaluating:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", 
   "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar"}]
```

That produces a Notebook like this:

[image]

The problem is that you lose access to the menu so you would need to restore it before using menu item.  You could do that by evaluating:

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
  WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", 
   "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}]
```

For convenience these two commands could be put in Buttons or a Palette:

```
Column[{
   Button["Hide Menu Bar", 
    SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
     WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", 
       "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar"}]],
   Button["Show Menu Bar", 
    SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
     WindowElements -> {"StatusArea", "MemoryMonitor", "MagnificationPopUp", 
       "HorizontalScrollBar", "VerticalScrollBar", "MenuBar"}]]
}] // CreatePalette
```

[image]