# Create a notebook with no menu bar

Tags: notebooks

I would like to create a notebook with a specific name and no menu bar. The following code:

```
  nb = CreateNotebook[Background -> LightBlue, Magnification -> 0.7, 
  WindowMargins -> {{1300, Automatic}, {Automatic, 11}}, 
  WindowSize -> {300, 900}]
```

creates a notebook, but I can't find anything about suppressing the menu bar or naming the window.

Comment: `WindowTitle -> "Name", WindowToolbars -> {}`?

Comment: By 'menu bar' do you mean the `File Edit Insert Format ...` menu?

Comment: Yes.  The File, Edit ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [57593](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57593/5478)