# Using Mathematica as a data visualization front end for .Net applications?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I have a C# application that has 3-dimensional data that I wish to plot.  Controls in C# for surface modeling are, in my experience, rather limited.  I wish to have my C# application send the 3D point mesh data to Mathematica `Plot3D` and display the result in a winform or some other front end (notebook?).

Essentially, my goal is to use Mathematica as a generalized data visualization tool from my C# applications.

So far, I have been able to generate a picture file from Mathematica that I put in a `MathPictureBox` control which resides on a winform.  However, I would like the interactivity you get when using `Plot3D` from a notebook.  Is this possible?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of ["Is it possible to embed the Mathematica editor?"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5204/245)

Comment: @Jens I'm not sure I agree.  I presume the interactivity that is asked for in this question is limited to the scaling and rotation of Graphics3D objects rather than a fully working Notebook interface.  I think it is a distinct question although it may have a common answer.

Comment: You can embed the Plot as a CDF using a WebView component as Jens pointed out or use .NET/Link to pass the viewing angle to Mathematica and get back the resulting image (I would imagine the second option to be slower, i.e. less interactive, and more complex, but I'm just guessing).

Comment: I was only looking at having interactivity in the form of rotation and scaling as Mr.Wizard rightly pointed out.  However, Jens' link looks promising.  Ajasja's latter option would be much less dynamic but could serve as a fallback approach.  Thank you all.

Comment: @Jens I tried your instructions in the linked page and could not read data into the html-embedded CDF, getting an error about Get not allow in sandboxed mode.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry - that's all I could think of right now...

Comment: @Jens No problem; seems like the Wolfram Player Pro might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer; but 7 years later, I have comfortably settled on using gnuplot as a generalized data visualization front-end (with full interactivity) for my .NET applications.