# How to output from a .NET console app to an existing Notebook in Mathematica?

Tags: .netlink

I'm wondering if its possible push output from a .NET console application to an existing Notebook that is open in Mathematica.

The reason I'd like this is that I want to use Mathematica as a "debugging console" for intermediate calculations that I am performing in .NET, by pushing out text, graphics, etc.

p.s. I'm fairly familiar with C# and Mathematica, so all I want to know is if this is possible, or not.

Comment: It is possible via JLink (see the JLink docs for details, my quick search resulted in [this link](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/JLink/Part1.InstallableJavaCallingJavaFromMathematica/ExamplePrograms/JLink1.3.8.html), but the updated version of this is now incorporated into the current JLink tutorial). I would guess .NET link should make this possible too.

Answer (score 3):

See http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingNotebooksFromTheKernel.html

If we send the following four commands to the Mathematica Kernel, via Net/Link, it will create a new notebook, and graph the result of an equation:

```
n = CreateWindow[]
NotebookWrite[n, "Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,6 Pi}]"]
SelectionMove[n, All, CellContents]
SelectionEvaluateCreateCell[n]
```

Here is the output in Mathematica. I think this is pretty cool: now I can use Mathematica as a kind of super charged debugging console from a .NET application, one which can plot graphic as well as print text. Any output graphs can then be interacted with, i.e. rotated, animated, etc.

[image]

**Update**

Unfortunately, this didn't end up working at all.

The following command does not work from .NET/Link, as its a function call contained in the user interface, and not the kernel:

```
n = CreateWindow[]
```

Currently, I'm still stuck. The only option I can think of is to create a standalone Windows service that sits in the background, accepting arrays from the standalone .NET app, and serving them to a Mathematica Notebook on demand (I havn't implemented this yet).