# Is there anyway to use a named argument in calling mathematica from .NET？

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I want to write a .NET program calling Mathematica as a computing engine. But here is a problem that argument a1 is not a constant and its value depends on `a1=str1+str2`. There is a mathematica function(fun1) I need to call and the argument of fun1 is a string. In Mathematica, I program like `fun1["@150"]`. But now, the problem is coming. Firstly, I think I can call fun1 like this:

```
Dim ml As IkernelLink = MathLinkFactory.CreateKernelLink()
ml.Evaluate("fun1[a1]")
```

But I found it is wrong, because in Mathematica the argument of fun1 is essentially a string. But here we also can not use `ml.Evaluate("fun1["a1"]")`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your argument is a string, you just need to place a backslash before the quote.

```
ml.Evaluate("fun1[\"a1\"]")
```

This also works for declaring variables and using them in a later calculation:

```
ml.evaluate("a1=\"string1\"<>\"string2\"");
ml.waitForAnswer();
ml.getString();
ml.evaluate("StringTake[a1,13]");
ml.waitForAnswer();
result = ml.getString();
```

Comment: thanks ChadK's, but you don't understand the problem. The argument a1 should be defined in the VB program. like I must Dim a1 As String. then I will call fun1 and pass a1 to fun1.

Comment: Since you know the form that MathLinkFactory functions expect, can you create them in vb?  Maybe something like this "fun1[\" <> a1 <> "\"]" ?

Comment: Yeah, according to your suggestion, I get it work. Just code like this <ml.Evaluate("fun1["""+a1+"""]")>. Thanks!@ChadK

Answer (score 1):

I believe all you need is the following.  It doesn't connect to the already running kernel, therefore you will have to define your function like so `"fun1[a_]:=Print[a];"` in some way.  In constructs a new kernel.

```
ml.Evaluate("fun1[\"a1\"]")
```

I can't tell for certain by your question though.

Comment: I have tried just like you said. But in vb.net, it use the "" instead of "\. So I tried ml.Evaluate("fun1[""a1""]"). but it's not work!

Comment: @yteen it doesn't connect to the already running kernel, therefore you will have to define your function like so `"fun1[a_]:=Print[a];"` in some way.  In constructs a new kernel.

Comment: I don't think so @LiamWilliam. The link is ok, because I use a constant string instead a1 like ml.Evaluate("fun1[""constant string""]") and it is work.

Comment: @yyteen you need to post all your code otherwise we can't help.  You have either most likely attached the function to the `FrontEnd` or have it installed in a package somewhere.  [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9980/how-to-output-from-a-net-console-app-to-an-existing-notebook-in-mathematica?rq=1) is somewhat related and demonstrates how the Kernel doesn't hook in with the FrontEnd and doesn't always work.

Comment: thank you @LiamWilliam ! I have solved the problem with coding <ml.Evaluate("fun1["""+a1+"""]")>