# How to remove scroll bars from embedded CDF

Tags: cdf-format, html, deployment

I am using the deploy command to embed a CDF file in an HTML page. I am using the annoying but currently necessary `fullscreen:'true'` trick to reveal the <kbd>"Enable Dynamics"</kbd> button.

Regardless of what size arguments I use in the cdf.embed function, I get an unnecessary vertical scroll bar in the result rendered in the web page. How can I get rid of this?

Are there other undocumented arguments to cdf.embed?

Comment: Welcome over here! We have met almost 20 years ago on the ARVO conference in Sarasota, but you probably don't recall that. BTW If you'd register, you'd be better able to use the site here (includes voting, commenting, and more).

Comment: I've read the plugin code and it seems that any javascript present in the fourth argument is just passed on. So, any javascript setting that removes the bar would do. Unfortunately, I don't know javascript, so, I can't help here.

Comment: If you have access to a web server account, you can perhaps avoid the issue you're having by serving the `CDF` directly, _not_ embedded in an HTML page. I noted down the steps for this in the [linked answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1796/245). This assumes all your content is in the `CDF` and you just don't like the scrollbar because it's surrounded by nothing else anyway.

Comment: Sjoerd: Amazing to hear that we met long ago! I think I am registered. Let me know if you know otherwise. I see my username at the top of the page.