# How to use and input audio wav file into a Wolfram demonstration

Tags: sound, deployment

I am trying to send a Wolfram demo, which contains a sound wav file.

`sound = Import["C:/myfile.wav", "Data"];
snd := sound[[1]]; or snd = sound[[1]];`

Is it possible to convert the wav file into the data set,- 
and in this form to insert in the demonstration? Or is there a problem with my Internet connection when uploading the demo?
In what form do you have to prepare audio *.wav files for use in Wolfram demonstrations? What kind of audio compression is needed for this purpose?

Comment: `Compress` returns a string which can be `Uncompress`ed into whatever was originally compressed. You could have something like `s=string` with the appropriate string, but I don't know if this is allowed in demonstrations (and you'd need to fold the cell closed)

Comment: The demonstrations are powered by CDFs, which unfortunately prohibit `Import` commands. I asked a similar question a few months back, "[Deploying Mathematica Content Online](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1787/deploying-mathematica-content-online)." You have to have the data all in the notebook so it can be self contained.

Answer (score 12):

Due to security restrictions some functions such as `Import`, `Uncompress`, or OS access functions cannot be used as a part of Demonstrations code, including the `Initialization`. So a generally great idea by @acl comment about compression will not work on Demonstrations site (but it's really ncie to use otherwise). This is what you get if you try to use `Uncompress` function inside a Demonstration code:

[image]

But this is what you can do. When you import a .WAV file into Mathematica notebook it has a very simple structure:

```
s = Import[ "ExampleData/rule30.wav"]
```

[image]

```
s // InputForm
```

[image]

Basically it is a simple list of numbers wrapped into functions [**Sound**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sound.html) and [**SampledSoundList**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SampledSoundList.html). You can extract these data and store them in a variable:

```
data = List @@ s[[1]];

ListLinePlot[data[[1]], PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image]

which will also (besides the data list) include the sampling frequency:

```
data[[2]]
```

> ```
> 44100
> ```

Include this data in `Initialization` for your demonstration:

[image]

Then inside the `Manipulate` you can restore your sound identically to the original as

```
Sound[SampledSoundList @@ data]
```

[image]

Browse [**these Demonstrations**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=Audio) to see how other people deal with audio data.

Comment: Excuse me, “You cannot use Import function as a part of Demonstrations code”, - in general, or only in the "Manipulation" section. Can I put Import function in the Initialization?
«Then inside the Manipulate you can restore your sound identically to the original as…»-
Restore from data placed in “Initialization” section. Can I use data from external *.nb document (file). Thanks again for the response to the primitive questions.

Comment: @Alexander I changed the beginning of my answer to reflect on your last comment.