# Embed CDF into an Apple iBook?

Tags: programming, output-formatting, manipulate

**Edit**
From the comments I received and verifying the information about CDF at wolfram.com, it appears that it is presently impossible to embed CDF into iBooks.
WRI does not appear to be happy with this state of affairs, and promises to provide updates if and when CDF for the iPad is supported by Apple.

---

My question is related to an earlier question, [How can I embed a Manipulate...in my website using CDF?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-can-i-embed-a-manipulate-or-other-interactive-graphics-in-my-website-using).

Has anyone had success in getting CDF to work in Apple iBooks?

There are  some lovely examples of how to use [Computable Document Format](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/) (CDF) to embed Mathematica applets into electronic textbooks
in Pearson's [Calculus: Early Transcendentals textbook](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/BriggsCochraneCalculus/BriggsCochraneCalculus.cdf). See also Eric Schulz's [Sharing Wisdom Gained in Publishing a CDF ebook](http://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2011/electronic-publishing.html) and a video by him [here](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/information-kit/developing-interactive-textbooks-with-cdf.html).

Apple's [iBooks Author](http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/) does not currently accept code such as that shown in the [Vornoi diagram example](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/adopting-cdf/deploying-cdf/web-delivery.html). It does have an Author widget, called HTML, for accepting HTML in [DashCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Before learning to use DashCode (or seeking out someone who does) I'd like to know whether this is a promising option for publishing CDF applets in ebooks.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first question would be: do the devices on which your iBook will be viewed also allow you to install the CDF player? If not, then that's the end of it. The FAQ says CDF doesn't run on the iPad: http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/faq/

Comment: Note also that Author widgets are not permitted to access the Internet.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the link. It says "Is CDF Player available for iPad?
The iPad is an important part of our CDF strategy. Contact us for more details about when CDF support for this platform becomes available."  So WRI is apparently interested in using the platform even though it isn't currently viable due to decisions by Apple.

Comment: @cormullion This, of course, impedes the use of curated data. Not good.

Comment: Note the 17 Februrary 2012 Wolfram Blog article, http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/02/17/a-preview-of-cdf-on-ipad/, which references Theo Gray's O'Reilly conference talk. You'd think Gray knows what's going on here, given that he's cofounder of Wolfram Research.

Comment: @murray Gray's remarks confirm Wolfram Research's interest in the platform. It remains to be seen whether WRI and Apple will reach a licensing agreement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first question would be: do the devices on which your iBook will be viewed also allow you to install the CDF player? If not, then that's the end of it. The [FAQ](http://wolfram.com/cdf/faq) says CDF doesn't run on the iPad (yet?).

Just as an aside: when I saw that FAQ, I was reminded of [Wolfram Publicon](http://www.wolfram.com/products/publicon/) (there was a similar FAQ for it ten years ago, and it had a very similar statement along the lines of: the release is just around the corner, just contact us...).